# Strange replacement behaviour (braces + parentheses)

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

I'm using the Azure Translator (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx).  if I translate to Swedish this string:

> we {1} had it

I get back what I'd expect:

> vi {1} hade det

but, most puzzlingly, this:

> we {2} had it

returns this (notice the braces got translated to parentheses):

> vi (2) hade det

what on earth??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all a matter of what the translation engine is trained on, and the  prevalent typographical conventions for the languages involved.  It's possible that for this (which looks like a C# format parameter), you could possibly have better results using the tech domain than the general domain.

Comment: that makes no sense.  why would it care that it's a 1 versus a 2?

Comment: Depends on the relative frequency of texts in the training text/translations. Modern translation systems don't do a structural parse. In this case, the system may have detected, based on the patterns in the training text that parentheses and curly brackets are interchangeable, . In popular generic textual usage, they probably are. In the context of format strings used in programs, they aren't (which is why: tech domain).  There is definitely improvements to be made in these systems in usage of special characters. In early translation systems, special characters just disappeared.;-)

Comment: thanks for the (rather late) explanation.  now it makes sense.  I guess I need to figure out how to switch domains